# In SharePoint Online is it possible to make an easier button to open the Approve/Reject modal screen for a list item from the list view/dispform page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, content-approval

In SharePoint Online Is it possible to use list/column view formatting JSON or similar to create a button that opens the Approve/Reject modal for the current list item?

I'd like to make a button that opens this modal from the list view:
[image]

This way managers who approve items do not need to search and/or click through the "..."/"more" menus to find the button to bring this screen up.

Answer (score 0):

JSON can only change the format of the display, and your requirements involve page design, which seems impossible to achieve through JSON.